# Convert char with hex value to String

Tags: c

If I have a character like the following:

```
wchar_t c = '\x0A'
```

What's an easy way to convert it so that it becomes something like:

```
wchar_t dst[] ==> "0A"
```

Basically, the hex value of c becomes a string value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integral value of `c` would be `0x0A` (`10` in base 10). You can use `sprintf` to format it as hex:

```
wchar_t c = '\x0A';
int c_val = c;
char string[3];

sprintf( string, "%.2X", c_val );
```

*Note the intermediate `c_val` variable is not needed, only added for clarity*

or you can do it manually:

```
int c_low = c & 0x0F;
int c_high = ( c & 0xF0 ) >> 4;

...translate c_low and c_high to its textual representation...
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple hexifier can be written quite easily. This one takes the target string as an input parameter:

```
unsigned int hexify(const wchar_t * src, char * dst, unsigned int dstlen)
{
  static const char alphabet[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

  unsigned int i = 0;
  while (*src && 2*i + 1 < dstlen)
  {
    dst[2*i]   = alphabet[*src / 16];
    dst[2*i+1] = alphabet[*src % 16];
    ++src;
    ++i;
  }
  dst[2*i] = 0;
  return i;
}
```

Usage:

```
char s[100];
hexify(some_wstr, s, 100);
```