# What is the best practice of using itoa()

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, memory-management, itoa

When I use itoa() it needs a char* _DstBuff, what is the best practice here?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int num = 100;

  // I'm sure here is no memory leak, but it needs to know the length.
  char a[10]; 

  // will this causue memory leak? if yes, how to avoid it?
  // And why can itoa(num, b, 10); be excuted correctly since b
  // has only allocated one char.
  char *b = new char; 

  // What is the difference between char *c and char *b
  // both can be used correctly in the itoa() function
  char *c = new char[10]; 

  itoa(num, a, 10);
  itoa(num, b, 10);
  itoa(num, c, 10);

  cout << a << endl;
  cout << b << endl;
  cout << c << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

the output is: 
100
100
100

So could anyone explain the differenct between `char *b = new char;` and `char *c = new char[10];` here?

I know `char *c` will dynamiclly allocate 10 chars, but that means `char *b` will only dynamically allocate 1 char, if I'm right about this, why is the output all correct?

actually which is the best practice of a, b, or c?

Comment: Why would you be using `itoa` when writing C++ anyway?

Comment: @Cody: Because `itoa` is more powerful (supports many different bases) and much much more efficient than other utilities in the standard library.

Comment: Given that nobody mentioned it...        

       `#include <stdlib.h>`
       `long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);`
       `long long int strtoll(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best practice: **Don't use it at all.**

*Why?* Because it's not in the standard.

*What should I do instead?* Use `std::to_string`.

(If you're really stuck having to use `itoa`, then use a large local static buffer, like `char[512]` or so -- if you want to be *really really* safe you can make the array size `sizeof(unsigned long long int) * CHAR_BIT + 2` or something like that so it can always hold any number expressed in any base, plus sign.)

Comment: std::to_string is in C++11 I'm using VC6 right now, is there any alternates?

Comment: @shengy: You could go via stringstreams, strstreams, use Boost.lexical_cast, or `sprintf`. For arbitrary bases you can easily roll your own, too. I've personally posted code for that on more than one occasion, though it's really very straightforward.

Comment: @shengy, one altenative is to get a decent compiler :-) Boom boom, thanks, I'm here all week.

Comment: VC6, wow. Considered upgrading to a modern compiler? That will save you a lot of work in the long run.

Comment: Here's one [related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8024386/596781) answer which you should be able to modify into something to convert a number (just divide the number by 16 each round), and you can also generalize it to any base (replacing 16 by the desired base).

Comment: I can't upgrade to a new complier, my company uses VC6 for a long time, and there are too many code to validate in this case

Answer (score 2):

In [this question I posed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion), you'll find *a dozen* efficient functions for converting an integer into a string, all of which allocate and return a `std::string` so you needn't worry about buffer overflow.  And several options in there are *blistering fast*.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is not a memory leak, but rather a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Basically, *you are getting lucky*. If you allocate only one character, but then write four characters to it, you are overrunning what has been allocated to you, and this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

`cout << b << endl;` : is incorrect, it is a buffer overflow.
because you allocate  1 byte of memory to contain one char. but, you write on it with `itoa()` 10+1chars.

so you have to allocate : `char * d = new char[11]; // 10 chars + '\0'(end of string char).`

then use `itoa(num , d , 10);`

in addition `itoa()` is non standard, so i prefer to use the standard `sprintf(d,"%d",num);`

and as said in the comment below, if you dont need `char*` and you can use `std::string`. use

```
string d = std::to_string(num);
```

Comment: 1/ It's `sprintf` with an `f`. 2/ That'll work for certain data types, but the C++ way is with string streams. `sprintf` is legacy C stuff, not type-extensible. 3/ Don't post when you're intoxicated ("tocontain" and "whit") :-)